# Python - Reading audio input and playing it simultaneously in real time

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming

I'm trying to create a guitar amp simulator.
I want to be able to read audio as input, and simultaneously play it, like a real guitar amp.

Couldn't find a lead on how to do this.
What python library is able to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Mido or a similar MIDI library?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it - My input is not MIDI, it's a direct audio from my sound card.